# TCP server not accepting right number of connections issued by client with small listen backlog

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, listen

I wrote a simple client program to issue a total of 10000 connections using 100 threads in a very small duration. And a simple server program with `listen backlog` set to 20 using epoll just to accept any new connection and record total connections number. I used `ulimit -n` to make sure it is larger than 20000 so there should be enough fd resource.

But after the server program `accept`ed like 8800, 9400 (not fixed) connections, it just stopped accepting any new connection. Client used blocking `connect` to establish connections, and all these 10000 calls of `connect` returned success. Then everything freezes, no more packet(no retransmission), no more accepted connection.

But once I closed the client program, the server program started to accept the remaining connections after closing some connections (and eventually accepted all 10000 connections and closed all these connections).

When I changed `backlog` to 100 or larger, all 10000 connections were accepted without any problem. (so it is not fd resource problem)

I know when accepting queue is full, linux may just ignore incoming `ACK` of a 3-Way handshake, leaving client's connection established but server's connection still unestablished, then let the retransmit mechanism work. And eventually server retransmit `SYN/ACK` pakcet, client responds with `ACK` to re-establish this connection if server's accepting queue is available. If there is no available space in queue, server ignores the `ACK` again.

But when I use wireshark to monitor these retransmissions, I found that just a small number of `SYN/ACK` retransmissions occurred (like 100~200, much less than number of lost connections, which is between 500~1500), and they are retransmitted just once or twice, all less than the value specified in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_synack_retries`. I inspected some of these retransmitted `SYN/ACK` packets, all of which received `ACK`s from client. But the number of retransmitted `SYN` packets from client was large.

So what's the underlying details?

Here are my codes:
[client](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xBKtFnNBWN/)
[server](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rv6vzRwF4t/)

Comment: Your events has only 20 elements and you passed it as a 1000 elements to epoll_wait function, is it normal ?

Comment: @TungLeThanh Oh, my fault. But even if I changed the array size to match EPOLL_WAIT_MAX_EVENTS，listenfd still can't accept enough connections. Though I'm curious why there isn't any memory segment fault, but suppose memory is well protected and no overflow occurrs, the small size should not cause lost connections. Afterall, listenfd is monitored by level trigger mode. I think problem is about connection establishing with syn queue and accept queue overflowed？

Comment: Your program runs smoothly on my system (Linux xxxxx 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux) : 
 `Try create:  10000
 Created:     10000
 Try connect: 10000
 Connected:   10000` `Accepted connection fd 10003 out of total 9999
Accepted connection fd 10004 out of total 10000`

Comment: @TungLeThanh Very sorry, did you just copy the newest code from the newest server code link? I set LISTENQ to 200 by mistake (for local test) when I repost it in pase.ubuntu.com and changed the server code link. It should be 20. It also runs smoothly on my system when I set LISTENQ to 200. I changed LISTENQ in server code link to 20.

Comment: I observed the same behavior as yours when reducing the backlog to 20. It seems that the kernel has ignored some of the SYNACKs when the accept queue is full.

Comment: @TungLeThanh The problem is when I closed the client after the server stopped accepting connections, the server started to accept new connections again. I inspected the packet client sent to server, all of them are FIN, no SYN or handshake ACK at all. All calls to connect on client returned success, which meant that the server had replied SYNACK at least once to each SYN sent by client.

Comment: @TungLeThanh And I didn’t found corresponding number of SYNACK retransmission. So these remaining unaccepted connections must still be somewhere in accepting queue or elsewhere, but the kernel failed to retrieve them . After the server received FIN from client, the kernel somehow found these unaccepted connections and generated epoll events. This is my guess.

Comment: It seems that the SYN cookie is activated for a temporary SYN flood. I just disable the syn cookie and your program run smoothly (with backlog = 20). The command used : `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=0`

Comment: @TungLeThanh So when the SYN cookie is temporarily activated, server will not allocate real data space for incoming SYN. Instead server simply replies a SYNACK. And when client’s ACK is received but server’s accept queue is still full, the ACK is ignored without any retransmission, so connections like this is established on client but lost on server ? It makes sense. But why does server continue to accept remaining connections when FIN arrives? It seems that it’s not part of connection establishing when SYN cookie is used?

Comment: @TungLeThanh I understood the scenario. Thank you very much. You can write an answer so I can select it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the backlog is full and SYN cookies are enabled, the kernel will activate the temporary SYN flood mode. This diagram shows how the cookies work ([source](https://www.giac.org/paper/gsec/2013/syn-cookies-exploration/103486)) :

[image]

When SYN flood was activated, all ACK sent from the client will be dropped. The server sent only SYN/ACK and the cookie to the client, the cookie cache table will be much smaller than socket table to maintain actives connection.
In this case, at the client side, the socket was considered as established but nothing is really opened at the server side (half-open connexion).

When the client application closes the socket, a FIN packet with ACK flag set will be sent to the server with a cookie inside, the server sees that the connection has an ACK, at this point, if the backlog is not full, the server will try to rebuild the connection from the cookie. If the cookie is valid (within a valid round trip), the socket will be added to backlog queue and can be handled as a normal socket.

It means that, when SYN cookie mode was activated and the backlog queue is not full, if the client sends some data to the server via the half-open sockets, accept() function will return new incomings connection.